# Finding how many times an item Appears in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Given an array of integers ranging from 1 to 60, i'm attempting to find how many times the numbers 1-44 appear in the array. Here is my method

```
public static void mostPopular(int[] list, int count)
    {
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[44];
        for (int i = 0; i<count;i++)
        {
            if (list[i]<45 )
            {
                numbers[i-1]=numbers[i-1]+1; //error here
            }
        }
        for (int k=0; k<44;k++)
        {
            System.out.println("Number " + k + " occurs " + numbers[k-1]+ "times");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to iterate through the array, list, that contains over 5000 numbers that are between 1-60, then test if that number is less than 45 making it a number of interest to me, then if the integer is 7 for example it would increment `numbers[6]` By 1. list is the array of numbers and count is how many total numbers there are in the array. I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line `numbers[i-1]=numbers[i-1]+1;`

with `numbers[list[i] - 1] = numbers[list[i] - 1] + 1;`

Now it will update the count of correct element.

Comment: I did that and it runs, but it's only incrementing `numbers[0]` and not any other indexes

Comment: you have to change his 'numbers[list[i]]' to 'numbers[list[i] - 1]' because in array the indexes start from index 0 to index 43.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `numbers[list[i]]` because that's your value which is smaller than 45. i goes up to 5000 and your array `numbers` is too small.

You should really start using a debugger. All the modern IDE have support for it (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, etc.). With the debugger you would have realized the mistake very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If your initial value is less than 45, it will add 1 to numbers[i-1]. However, since you start with i=0, it will try to add 1 to the value located at numbers[-1], which doesn't exist by law of arrays. Change i to start at 1 and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is `0`, `i-1` is `-1` -- an invalid index.  I think that you want the value from `list` to be index into `numbers`.  Additionally, valid indices run from `0` through `43` for an array of length `44`.  Try an array of length `45`, so you have valid indices `0` through `44`.

```
numbers = new int[45];
```

and

```
if (list[i] < 45)
{
    // Use the value of `list` as an index into `numbers`.
    numbers[list[i]] = numbers[list[i]] + 1;
}
```

Comment: what does the `&& list` do? I changed it to `numbers[list[i]] = numbers[list[i]] + 1;` but for some reason it's only incrementing `numbers[0]`

Comment: @user102817 I was going somewhere with that code, but decided against it and forgot to remove it.  I've removed it now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Very close, but a few indexing errors, remember 0-1 = -1, which isn't an available index.  Also, this isn't c, so you can call list.length to get the size of the list.
Try this (you can ignore the stuff outside of the mostPopular method):

```
class Tester{

   public static void main(String args[]){
       int[] list = new int[1000];
       Random random = new Random();
       for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
           list[i] = random.nextInt(60) + 1;
       }
       mostPopular(list);
   }

   public static void mostPopular(int[] list)
   {
       int[] numbers = new int[44];
       for (int i = 0; i< list.length ;i++)
       {
           int currentInt = list[i];

           if(currentInt<45 )
           {
               numbers[currentInt - 1] = (numbers[currentInt -1] + 1);
           }
       }
       for (int k=0; k<numbers.length; k++)
       {
           System.out.println("Number " + (k+1) + " occurs " + numbers[k]+ "times");
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers[i-1]=numbers[i-1]+1; //error here
```

change to

```
numbers[list[i]-1] += 1;
```

as `list[i]-1` because your `number[0]` store the frequency of `1` and so on.

we increase the corresponding array element with index equal to the list value minus 1

```
public static void mostPopular(int[] list, int count)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[44];
    for (int i = 0; i<count;i++)
    {
        //in case your list value has value less than 1
        if ( (list[i]<45) && (list[i]>0) )
        {
            //resolve error
            numbers[list[i]-1] += 1; 
        }
    }
    //k should start from 1 but not 0 because we don't have index of -1
    //k < 44 change to k <= 44 because now our index is 0 to 43 with [k-1]
    for (int k=1; k <= 44;k++)
    {
        System.out.println("Number " + k + " occurs " + numbers[k-1]+ "times");
    }
}
```